# VMware - Switch between macOS Guest and Host

Tags: virtualization, vmware, fullscreen

I am running macOS High Sierra as guest OS using VMware on a host running macOS High Sierra. The guest OS is running in full-screen.

I am looking for a mechanism (possibly a keyboard shortcut) to switch from guest OS to host while keeping guest full-screen in it's own separate Space/Desktop.

I am effectively looking for a key-sequence that will be **recognised only by** the host and **not** the guest instance of macOS.

Any idea about how to do this?

Comment: I'm guessing this is going to be same as a Remote Desktop structure... don't use the same key commands in both. I have all mine as non-defaults so I don't have to rely on others having to change them.

Comment: Sounds like a recipe for confusion  :)  I'm not going to try this as I don't want it, but you might look at the `VMware, Preferences...`, then `Keyboard & Mouse` tab, `Mac Host Shortcuts` sub-tab(??).